# Regex search term used in Notepad++ does not work with python

Tags: python, regex, twitter, notepad++

I'm working with a large .json filled with twitter bios and would like to extract screen_names. To prevent that the search also returns potential users mentioned in the bio section it is important only to extract the first match ofeach line.

When I open the file in Notepad++ I can use the following regex to do exactly that:

```
(^.*?)\K"screen_name": "(\w+)"
```

Using the same as part of an re.findall or re.search in python does not result in any matches.

I'm totally new to both Python and regex so I'm fairly certain I'm not fully aware of all the necessary coding.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Python `re` module does not support `\K` construct. NPP uses Boost, not Python `re`. In Python, read the file line by line and use `re.search` with `r'"screen_name":\s*"(\w+)"'` pattern and access Group 1 value.

Comment: Backslashes in python are special characters, so you need to escape them or use a raw string.

Comment: if it's a `.json` file you're looking at, it might be easier to use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module in Python.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your quick support, as I suspected it was no big trouble :) Special thanks to @wiktor stribizew. Final code is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by other users Python and Notepad use different search codes, and so to achieve my wanted result I deployed the following code:

```
  import re
  regex=re.compile(r'"screen_name":\s*"(\w+)"')
  with open("followers.json", "r") as f:
     for line in f:
        output=regex.search(line)
        with open("followers.txt", "a") as outp:
            outp.write(output.group(1)+"\n")
```

This will analyse your specified .json file, read it line by line, and save every first match of each line in the file "followers.txt".